# toggle animation on/off with angularjs ui-router and ng-animate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I want to switch an animation on and off using:
- AngularJS
- ui-router
- ng-animate

The current method i'm using toggles a parent class on/off. This removes the css animation from the dom element

However when I toggle the class off, it breaks the animation on the javascript side and angular doesn't put the animate classes back onto the element. Here's the html:

```
<div ng-class="{animate:pageanimate}">
    <p>pageanimate = {{ pageanimate }}</p>
    <p><a ng-click="pageanimate=!pageanimate">toggle animate</a></p>
    <div class="well" ui-view></div>        
</div>
```

And the css uses the animate class from the parent:

```
.animate .ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out 0.7s;
    -o-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out 0.7s;
    transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out 0.7s;
}
```

And a working plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/cAkseveonU8394FccjeL?p=preview

Comment: I don't get your problem. This works exactly as you intended.

Comment: If you toggle the animation off, then back on you notice it doesn't work the second time

Comment: something like this might work http://plnkr.co/edit/jpebBk?p=preview

Comment: Yea that looks pretty good. Im my experience `ng-animate` can be a bit frustrating because it's changed a lot recently. Also check out http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$animateProvider , maybe it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is how i did it in ui-router

```
  app.run(['$animate',function($animate){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

         //below are routes where animation is off
        if(toState.name=='portal.inbox' || toState.name=='portal.sent')
            $animate.enabled(false);            
        else
            $animate.enabled(true);

    });
 }]);
```

Comment: Almost, had to modify a little to make it work, but the idea of using $animate.enabled was correct! here is the working version http://plnkr.co/edit/fhBg7z51R4oUPL03QtlF?p=preview

Comment: I like it! You can shorten it to one line by moving the boolean: `$animate.enabled(toState.name!='portal.inbox' && toState.name!='portal.sent')`